# Laravel application deployed in sub directory all routes broken

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen people asking about routing to Controllers that are sitting in sub directories. But my issue is that my Laravel application itself is in a sub directory. The default route is working, IE "/", but everything else is not.

**This is what I have so far:**

1. The Laravel application is sitting in public_html/dashboard
2. I have put the .htaccess file that was sitting in dashboard/public into dashboard/ (The Laravel root dir)
3. I have changed the server.php file to index.php so the site can be accessed from dashboard/ and not dashboard/public
4. I have added ->prefix('dashboard') to the mapWebRoutes method in RouteServiceProvider:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{

    Route::middleware('web')
            ->prefix('dashboard') // <-- Added this
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

5. Added a prefix path to the assets function in helpers.php:

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("dashboard/public/".$path, $secure);
}
```

**My current routing setup**

My web.php has some simple routing so far, some may think that I should wrap Route::prefix('dashboard') around my routes, but this is why I have added the prefix to the RouteServiceProvider so my web.php file will always have that prefix regardless.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('', 'EnquiryController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('switch', 'EnquiryController@switch')->name('switch');
Route::get('view-enquiry/{id}', 'EnquiryController@viewEnquiry')->name('view-enquiry');
```

**A couple of notes:**

I know that the Laravel application should be entirely public, and the .env file should not be accessible.. but for now I want to get the application working, and I will deal with hiding it after.

Finally, going to dashboard/ DOES show me a perfect looking page, but any routes like dashboard/view-enquiry/52 or the Auth routes like dashboard/logout just return a 404 page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, maybe I am doing this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If you project is working perfectly in your local hosting all you need to do is!

1. Move all your project file into a **dashboard** in your **public_html** directory.
2. Move all the content of your project **public** folder to the root **public_html**.
3. The index.php file copied to the root **public_html** directory open it and make the following changes.

First

**Change this line**

require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

**To**

require **DIR**.'/dashboard/vendor/autoload.php';

Secondly

**Change this line**

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

**To**

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/dashboard/bootstrap/app.php';

There is no need of changing anything in your route.php

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, in your point number "2." you say move the content of public/* into public_html/* however the public_html directory has a lot of "junk" in so I don't really want to mix the laravel application public content with the current public_html root stuff. Everything else you say though makes good sense so far thanks :)

Comment: Ok! You can as well carryout the same process on that dashboard directory making it your project directory. Paste all the content of public into the dashboard and move the rest content into a new folder in the dashboard directory and make the same changes in the ** index.php**  so you can access your project with https://domainName.com/dashboard.      
 Now the reason of moving the rest content into a new folder in the dashboard directory is so that your environment file(.env) will not be vulnerable.